# YII2: Build an Model from differt tables

Tags: php, model, controller, yii2, crud

I'm new to Yii2 and I have problem with an model form more differt tables.

I have 3 tables with a different data-structure:

- JobOffer1 (Name, ID, Date, ...)
- JobOffer2 (JobName, StartDate, Location, ...)
- JobOffer3 (description, Start)

The target model is:
`Jobname`, `StartDate` (is present in all tables with different columns)

There are still restrictions for all requests to the tables.

**JobController.php**

```html
            ...

            // JobOffer1
            $model = [];
          
            $sql = "SELECT Name As Jobname, Date As StartDate
            FROM JobOffer1,
                Company1 cp1,
                ...
            WHERE (cp1.availability IS NULL OR cp1.availability = 0)
            AND ... ";

            $JobOffer1 = JobOffer1::findBySql($sql)->all();
            
            foreach ($JobOffer1 as $job) {
                array_push($model, $job);

            }

            // JobOffer2
            $sql = "SELECT JobName As Jobname, StartDate As StartDate
            FROM JobOffer2,
                TableXYZ xyz,
                ...
            WHERE xyz.value > 100
            AND ... ";

            $JobOffer2 = JobOffer2::findBySql($sql)->all();
            
            foreach ($JobOffer2 as $job) {
                array_push($model, $job);

            }

            // JobOffer3
            $sql = "SELECT description As Jobname, Start As StartDate
            FROM JobOffer3,

            $JobOffer3 = JobOffer3::findBySql($sql)->all();
            
            foreach ($JobOffer3 as $job) {
                array_push($model, $job);

            }

            $data = new ArrayDataProvider([
                'allModels' => $model
            ]);


             return $this->render('index', [
                'data' => $data,
            ]);
```

Currently, I'm build everything in the **controller** with an `Array`. It works, but it is very slow. And I cannot filter and search the data-array in the view.

What is the fastest and best solution? My idea is to build a JobModel by assembling JobOffser1-3 (with all conditions).

Would that be an idea and maybe someone has a snippet for me?!

Comment: [Best Practice for Models](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models) may help you. Is there is a relationship between this tables?

Comment: No, the tables are not related. There are different data-inputs for one model. The tables are in different databases (MSSQL), otherwise I merged them into the query (with joins).

Answer (score 0):

Use QueryBuider for create query for ActiveDataProvider, and use Union and fields aliases for join results from different tables by same names like this:

```
$queryB = new QueryBuider();
$q = (new Query)->select('field1')->from('table1')->union('(select fieldN as field1 from tableN)')->union('...');
$queryB->buld($q)
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataPrivuder(['query'=>$queryB]);
```